# Google App Script, TextOutput doesnt return message

Tags: google-apps-script

Story:
I am testing a **google apps script** which receives a file and sends an email to recipient containing a file content as the body of the message. I also want to let sender/user know that *"email sent successfully"*.

Problem:
Everything works fine untill it reaches the final line,

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("sent successfully!!!");
```

where it should return the success message to sender. but it sends http status error [302]. I am using dio package for sending http post request. I have also tested the returning line alone, it works fine.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(e.parameter.file),e.parameter.contentType,e.parameter.fileName);
  var body = blob.getDataAsString();
  MailApp.sendEmail("testEmail@gmail.com", "this is a test subject", body);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("sent successfully!!!"); //doesnt work
}
```

This code works just fine:

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("hello world!");
}
```

What am I doing Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`e.parameter` is `GET` parameter usually used for `GET` request

You should use `e.postData`